# jQuery input vs textarea on paste different behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been struggling to find a definite solution for this problem with paste on input.

I have got the following regex control on my input

```
var match = str.match(/^[^,]*,[^,]*,.*$/mg);
```

You can see the example of its usage on the following demo link. My problem is when I paste a content like

```
123, john smith, jack david
321, jackie ronal, david blah
```

into an **input** field, I get the whole content as a single entry whereas in the **textbox** it recognizes the new line and that is exactly what I am looking for (as you can see in the demo I procided).

Now, can anyone give me a nice solution to get this problem solved with **input** field would be great otherwise if I have to use textarea I need to find a way to make the textarea borders hidden but as far as my understanding there is no cross browser solution for it to do it nicely (hid all borders and resize icon in all browsers).

Here is the demo

http://jsfiddle.net/TCMcp/3/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What browser support do you need?  Is contenteditible an option?

Comment: all browsers mate. im not sure what do u mean by contenteditible. I simply need to paste content like the one I provided with two or more line and each line needs to be treated separately instead of once for all.

Comment: Nothing works on all browsers except a HTML 1.0 document :-)

Answer (score -1):

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HyKPE/1/)

Instead of an input, you can use a div with contenteditable set to true (this is technically incorrect, but provides support for IE).  Example styles can be found in the fiddle.

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="input"></div>
```

We can then get the text content using JavaScript.

```
$('#input').on('paste', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var str = $('#input').text();
        jsprint("pasted", str);
        $('#input').text(str); 
        var match = str.match(/^[^,]*,[^,]*,.*$/mg);             

    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: if you see the update of your example http://jsfiddle.net/HyKPE/2/ you can realize that the field still gets the whole content and alert it as whole instead of two parts. you can see what I mean when paste into the textarea I provided in my example.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.  When I paste it, it shows as two separate alerts.  What browser are you testing on?

Comment: Can you please test this:
123, john smith, jack
321, jackie ronal, david

Comment: If you copy/paste the text from your question, it works for me.  What browser are you using?

Comment: You are right the example provided works fine! there might be a mistake on my regex then. any idea what am I missing?